# OpenCV: Object abstraction after background subtraction?

Tags: c++, opencv, filter, object-detection, background-subtraction

I need a background subtraction application that gives me as a ouput a black/white image with an abtract representation of the objects. See the image below for further information. It should be an online algorithm so the background adapts to illumination changes, like in video surveillance, but it shouldn't adapt too fast to be able to detect objects appearing for a longer time.

[image: Program sketch]

I tried this in OpenCV with the code blow, and there are two main problems:
1. It's noisy
2. Although I set the parameter in BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(30000,16.0,false) high, the background adapts too fast.

I don't need any object tracking.

It should be a standard application of background but I couldn't find an example code. How can this be implemented? Thanks alot.

```
...
for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        bg.operator ()(frame,fore);
        bg.getBackgroundImage(back);
        cv::findContours(fore,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        cv::drawContours(frame,contours,-1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);
        cv::imshow("Frame",fore);
        cv::imshow("Background",back);
        if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
...
```

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html#py-background-subtraction